# What type of temperature sensor is this?

Tags: sensor, identification

I have a bunch of these temperature sensors that I want to use for a project, but I can't find any information about the specifications of it.  There are no markings on it to aid in identification.

I have hooked it to a multimeter, and it appear to be a simple varying resistance.  At body temperature it reads about 6.5kΩ, and at room temperature about 11kΩ.  Is it simply a variable resistance?

[image: Unidentified Thermoprobe]

Comment: Actually u got two points (X,Y ) 
(body temp , 6.5 K ) , (room temp , 11 k) 
from this points you can get equation : R(resistance)= A * Temp + C (linear equation , A & C are constants ) 
So no need for the datasheet , except finding the max rating

Comment: Yes indeed, but I wanted to a) be sure this is actually a 'real' measurement and not a side-effect, and b) find out what the limits and performance of the part are.  Doesn't need to be 100% perhaps, but be nice to at least have an idea it's correct.

Comment: I's good to look for the datasheet, but doubling its value for about 10 degrees of temperature seems showing that is a NTC (Negative Temperature Coefficient) thermistor

Comment: Great, that helps - it looks exactly like a bunch of other "Thin Film NTC Thermistors" out there.

Comment: @xsari: A linear approximation is not usually very good for these kinds of thermistors.  If I remember right, the real equation based on the physics is exponential based.  Over human range temperatures, a third order polynomial is usually good enough.

Comment: @OlinLathrop thx for thr info

Comment: What you can do is: 1) take a random datasheet of a 10k thermistor (see Fake Name's answer), then 2) try to sweep in temperature, using well-known values, and measure the resistance to check if the curve matches.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't use a linear approximation in the end, but pinched a "Steinhart-Hart Thermistor Equation" example I found on the Arduino site.  Seems to match pretty well with the values I'd expect (body temp!), so I'll see how it goes. I'll play around with it in some water with another thermometer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is a Kapton-laminated/Kapton-encapsulated thermistor. From the description, it is a NTC (negative temperature coefficent) device.

([Kapton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapton) is the material the amber film is composed of. It's a high-temperature polymer)

The actual packaging is fairly unusual. The *only* place I have ever seen thermistors like that is in computer sensing hardware. I also did not have much luck finding places where you can purchase similar devices.

---

For what it's worth, this is actually **not** a *thin film* device. It's a standard thermistor, packaged in a film enclosure. Thin film, in an electronics context, typically means that the *resistive/active element* is composed of a thin film, generally deposited on a substrate, typically with a vacuum deposition process.

In this case, you have a standard chip-type thermistor, which is laminated into a polymer film.

---

As an aside, if the part has no marking on it, you will likely **never** find a datasheet for your particular part. However, from the values you specify, it sounds like a bog-standard 10K thermistor (e.g. 10K @ 25°C, which is a common way to specify them), so it should be easy to use even in lieu of having a real datasheet.